# Issue with graphics and multicol

Tags: diagrams, multicol

For my paper I'm using `multicols{2}` and i assume that this gives me some issue with including graphics.

I use the following commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.4cm} 
\usepackage{cite}     
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Results}

\begin{figure}

\centering 

\includegraphics{1Bild} 

\end{figure} 

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

However, I the picture does not get displayed at all and I receive no error message. I tried using the same command in a new file without multicol:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 

\centering 

\includegraphics{1Bild} 

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

and it works perfectly.

Comment: What package are you using in the first case?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.4cm}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{paralist}

Comment: `multicol` environment doesn't allow floats.  However, you can use `starred` version, ie `\begin{figure*}` and `\end{figure*}`.

Comment: Thanks, the graphic is being displayed now. I removed the centring command and the picture is now more or less in line with my left column. However, the caption i wrote still spans the whole codument. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Not the perfect way!  However, a workaround would be: 
`\parbox{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}{\caption{Here goes the caption.}}`.  You may take care of the vertical white space on the next column!

Comment: Thanks. The command put put the caption to the right of my picture, making it look rather odd. Im sure I'll get it to work if i play around a bit. Would another option be to just turn multicol off and on again whenever needed?

Comment: A `\par\noindent` just before `\parbox` will solve this issue.